# Securing Spring websocket

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-websocket

I am using Spring Websocket in my application. I am using `WebSocketConfigurer` to create websocket. Now, I need to make sure that this websocket is secure. However, all the examples, that I have come across of Spring Security and WebSocket, are using `AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` which is then secured using `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`. Is there any example which shows how to secure websocket created using `WebSocketConfigurer` ?

Comment: So your question is around how to have Spring Session use , not Spring Security? If so, it sounds as though this is related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/98

Comment: I think so. Basically, I have an application which has a REST service and a websocket. The clients are going to request on the REST service for data and that data will be served through websockets. I need to make sure that both, REST and websocket, endpoints are secure. To achieve that I thought I could use Spring Security/Spring Session. However, I am struggling to get this working. Can you point to an example which could help me?

Comment: For now I think you will need to base your configuration off of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/30d4ea996bf0138382a09dcf6005acde6234f558/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/socket/config/annotation/AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.java

Comment: Well.. I have managed to write, what I think is, a secure websocket using Spring Session and Spring security. If you are interested, I can put the code on github. That way you can tell me if there is anything I am missing... Thanks for your help so far anyway...

Comment: There is still no nice solution of this problem: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/340

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special to secure your websocket. It will follow the same mechanism that you have selected for your REST end-point. Basically spring-security provides uniform security mechanism for both as websocket also starts with initial HTTP handshake.
If you want to see something in action, you should look at [portfolio app](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) that spring docs for websocket refers to.

Comment: In the provided example the csrf is simply disabled... which is not what we want for a production app